# Database Update and Join

Tags: mysql

I have a database called address with two tables companies and latlon

Each table has a road, block and building No. And the latlon Table has lat lon fields.

I would like to update 'companies' to include the lat lon, if the road, block and building No is the same as in the latlon database.

Here is what I have:

```
UPDATE latlon t
JOIN address a USING (Building, RoadNo, Block)
SET t.lat2 = a.lat, t.lon2 = a.lon
WHERE t.lat2 = '' AND t.lon2 = ''
```

Doesn't work for some reason. It just keeps freezing the window. (150k Rows), when I check if there are any updates happening. Nothing updates. Anyone know why?

latlon Table:

```
Building RoadNo Block id lat2 lon2 
123      456    789   1  45.4 58.6
```

Companies Table:

```
CrNo Building RoadNo Block id lat lon
12   123      456    789   1  empty empty
```

Comment: *Doesn't work for some reason* makes no sense please explain what is the problem any error you get or data is not properly updated ?

Comment: Try to do the corresponding `SELECT` and check for errors/correct output (i.e. that it will return desired rows)

Comment: Sorry Khalid. I updated my question..

Comment: Unless you have good reasons to filter out the records in `latlon` where `lat2` and `lon2` are already set, the `WHERE` clause is probably not needed there. If in the current records `lat2` and `lon2` happen to be `NULL`, they will not be updated with your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that the join is taking a really long time.  Try creating the following index:

```
create index address_building_roadno_block on address(Building, RoadNo, Block)
```